# Core data - loading issue

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using core data to save and load some simple instances containing som binary data, strings and date. Saving is working as intended, but when i load data into my UITableViewController, the data is "corrupted", and it's  as if all the fields in the objects are set to nil (The wrapper object exists in the correct amount, but all strings and binary data is nil, and all dates are set to 1970.01.01..) - **This only happens after the app is killed.** **The app can go to the background and the data persists through it as intended.**

I created the Context, StoreCoordinator, and Model in my AppDelegate, and this is pure apple boilerplate code (from creating a Core Data project) so i don't see the error happening there.

What's important is that i have verified that the data in the SQLite file is actually stored correctly, so this must have something to do with the loading. Here is how i load the data in my UITableView subclass:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ScreenshotInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
pics = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (!pics) {
    [NSException raise:@"Fetch failed" format:@"reAson: %@",[error localizedDescription]];
}
```

Another important note is, that i don't see how the above code can be wrong, because i can create an instance of the stored data, save it, and then immediately go to my UITableView and see the new data being loaded perfectly. Only killing the app, causes this weird stuff. I just can't to seem any solution to this, so any suggestions are welcome.

---------EDIT - Added code for PersistentStoreCordinator + Model ---------

Instantiation of PersistenStoreCoordinator:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DogTrack.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType   configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }    

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Instantiation of the model:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

Comment: It seems like the persistent store isn't writing on the disk. Can you post the code where you create it, along with the managed object model  creation?

Comment: I inserted extra code.

Could you elaborate what you mean? i already confirmed that the data is put correctly into the DB, and the objects have the correct values in the DB.

Comment: Forget about this ; are you sure you save the context when you insert your objects?

Comment: Yes i am 100% sure - Also like i said, i have verified that the SQLite file contains the expected values, so, i don't see anything wrong with the saving.

Comment: Maybe when you restart your app, for reasons that evades me, your SQLite store `DogTrack.sqlite` entity attributes are being overwritten to a default `NULL` during the restart process. Perhaps the location of your call to persist data (`save`) is located in your code such that it may cause a save using NULL values **before** your call to your `NSFetchedResultsController` has properly created your `fetchedObjects`? I'd set breakpoints in your start-up code and literally stop, reload your SQLite db in Terminal, check the data, until you find at least when the data is overwritten.